# How to configure jenkins to handle cmake flags matrix

Tags: jenkins, cmake

I have a cmake projects with some compilations flags (-Denable_optims, -Denable_coverage), and I want to compile all the possible combinations of flags with jenkins. The problem I get is that jenkins labels seems to don't work with cmake plugin. Is there a workaround with cmake or jenkins configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to stop using the cmake plugin. Simply call cmake from a shell build step. Then you can use all the variables from a matrix-configuration project in your shell build step, e.g. by setting some CMake variables.